# In the context of work, is a report and direct report the same thing?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Essentially what I'm asking is whether or not a report and a direct report are the same thing --- are the words synonyms?

Oxford Dictionary defines a report as someone who reports to a fellow employee, so in my estimation the answer is yes.

Comment: So, one has to decide to use either direct report or indirect report?

Comment: They're not the same thing. You report to your boss's boss, but not directly. Example, assuming a particular branch of the organisation has six sections: the branch manager's direct reports are their secretary and the six section managers. Each section manager's direct reports are the lower-level employees in their section. But everyone in the branch reports to the branch manager, and everyone including the branch manager reports to the CEO.

Answer (score -1):

*Report* is, as a noun, *an account given of a particular matter, especially in the form of an official document, after thorough investigation or consideration by an appointed person or body, or the information contained in such document*. As a verb it is the act of providing such document of information.

A *direct report* is a concept in business and administration, which is not a report, but a person. It is an employee who is managed by and reports to someone else immediately up the chain of command in the organizational structure.

Comment: @KannE That is what I am referring too.\